# Probs removing the Freehub from Mavic Ksyrium Pro UST

Tags: freehub

Finally managed to remove end caps after reading helpful tips on this site... now cannot get the freehub off. Researched the manual... there do not appear to be any further retention devices, but its seems fixed. I'm worried about damaging the unit... any tips?

Comment: I have the Cosmic Elite wheels, so I'm not sure if this applies so FWIW:

Comment: Managed to chat with mechanic at Pearson in Kingston Upon Thames... He suggested putting the cassette back on and tapping it through the spokes to see if that will shift it. He confirmed that there is nothing else that holds the freehub on, so I'm going to give it. a go tomorrow.